# Why am I not seeing all the partitions on my hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I am looking at the System Information of Windows 7 on my new Lenovo T400 laptop.

It says that it has three partitions, but there are only two visible drives. Where is the "missing" partition (the one with 1.17 GB) and what it is for?

#### Hard drive information

```
Description                 Disk drive  
Manufacturer                (Standard disk drives)  
Model                       WDC WD2500BEVS-08VAT2  
Bytes/Sector                512  
Media Loaded                Yes  
Media Type                  Fixed hard disk  
Partitions                  3  
SCSI Bus                    0  
SCSI Logical Unit           0  
SCSI Port                   0  
SCSI Target ID              0  
Sectors/Track               63  
Size                        232.88 GB (250,056,253,440 bytes)  
Total Cylinders             32,301  
Total Sectors               488,391,120  
Total Tracks                7,752,240  
Tracks/Cylinder             240  
Partition                   Disk #0, Partition #0  
Partition Size              1.17 GB (1,258,291,200 bytes)  
Partition Starting Offset   1,048,576 bytes  
Partition                   Disk #0, Partition #1  
Partition Size              221.95 GB (238,313,009,152 bytes)  
Partition Starting Offset   1,259,339,776 bytes  
Partition                   Disk #0, Partition #2  
Partition Size              9.77 GB (10,485,760,000 bytes)  
Partition Starting Offset   239,572,353,024 bytes
```

#### Drives

```
Drive                C:  
Description          Local Fixed Disk  
Compressed           No  
File System          NTFS  
Size                 221.95 GB (238,313,005,056 bytes)  
Free Space           202.36 GB (217,280,110,592 bytes)  
Volume Name          Windows7_OS  
Volume Serial Number CC3B4EF0  

Drive                E:  
Description          CD-ROM Disc  

Drive                Q:  
Description          Local Fixed Disk  
Compressed           No  
File System          NTFS  
Size                 9.77 GB (10,485,755,904 bytes)  
Free Space           3.28 GB (3,519,356,928 bytes)  
Volume Name          Lenovo_Recovery  
Volume Serial Number B63E336A
```

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to this yourself?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question. If you could provide any further information so the question might possibly be solved, that would be great. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a diagnostic or recovery partition created by Lenovo.  It is usually accessed through the diagnostics menu or BIOS menu at startup.  Often the blue button at top of keyboard to left of power button will work on startup for this.  There is usually a prompt during boot.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think so. Drive Q is already for Lenovo_Recovery, while I refer " Partition #0" as the missing one.

Comment: Sorry Tim: I need to learn to read! :-) What does Disk management tell you.  Some systems also have a "System Tools" or "OS Tools" partition.  ALos have seen some that the factory just leaves a small unused portion of the drive.  Some Dells we have received have been like that

Comment: Thanks DaveM. Disk Management has three volumes: Lenovo_Recovery(Q:), SYSTEM_DRV and Windows7_OS(C:). All of three are simple layout, basic type and NTFS. SYSTEM_DRV, which is actually "Partition #0", has status as healthy (SYstem, Active, Primary Partition) and capacity as 1.17GB and 45% free. Lenovo_Recovery(Q:) is also healthy(Primary Partition). Windows7_OS(C:) is healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition). Although having list some info here, I still don't know what "Partition #0" or SYSTEM_DRV is for.

Comment: Have you tried to browse it, probably then you'll find out what it is for. Just assign a drive letter and look through it ;)